# App center problem after upgrading to Jólnir

Tags: updates, appcenter, update-manager

I installed the elementary OS Jólnir as ISO in my current partition where the Odin was installed.
Everything seems to be okay but there is one problem in the app center, when I want to update the operating system updates this error is shown:

```
fwupd-signed: Depends: fwupd (= 1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.2) but 1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev is to be installed
```

I installed `sudo apt-get install libfwupdplugin1` but the problem is still there.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it was from the Pop OS stable release's PPA, I do not know when and how it was added but with the command below I solved it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -ys ppa:system76-dev/stable --remove
```